# Ruby on Rails Devise encrypted password read from C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ruby, devise, password-encryption

We have a Ruby on Rails app that uses the **Devise** gem for user handling, including creating and authenticating user passwords. The passwords are encrypted in the MySQL database obviously. We are using Devise defaults for how it encrypts the password. Now we have another small same-LAN side app that (a C# ASP.NET app) needs to authenticate with a user/password directly with the database to do some read-only operations.

How can we best mimic what Devise does for user/password authentication in the C# ASP.NET app against the very same data in the MySQL database?

Essentially, I need to figure out how to recreate Devise's valid_password? method in C# .NET

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Models/DatabaseAuthenticatable#valid_password%3F-instance_method

```
# File 'lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb', line 46

def valid_password?(password)
  return false if encrypted_password.blank?
  bcrypt   = ::BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_password)
  password = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("#{password}#{self.class.pepper}", bcrypt.salt)
  Devise.secure_compare(password, encrypted_password)
end
```

Comment: Hello streamline. Can you update us with how you resolved this need?

Comment: @Streamline Were you able to work out on this?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the question correctly. What you want to do is authenticate a user on you .NET application using the credentials on your rails application. If so, I would suggest implementing an oauth server on the ruby side and a client in you .NET code. As for the server you have several gems that provide this functionality including

1. [oauth-ruby](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth-ruby)
2. [doorkeeper](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper)
3. [oauth2-provider](https://github.com/songkick/oauth2-provider)

Comment: Thanks for your input on how to build up a formal oath authentication process between the apps, I can certainly see us using something like that if we decided to go down that route and oauth is perfect for apps that are in dissimilar networks. However, in this case we are not looking at such a sophisticated, elaborate and permanent change effort for both the rails app and the C# app. I do literally want to the C# app to be able to use the same database (it is on the same LAN) for now, especially at this stage it is a prototype and we want as few changes as possible to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

Devise uses BCrypt for password storage, and so thankfully the verification process is fairly simple. Install the `BCrypt.Net` NuGet package (or any other BCrypt implementation), and then do this:

```cs
public static bool ValidPassword(string userSuppliedPassword, string hashedAndSaltedPassFromDatabase)
{
    return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(userSuppliedPassword, hashedAndSaltedPassFromDatabase);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar requirement of verifying already existing users from the C# application.

I used package [bcrypt.net - next](https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net) for BCrypt.

Here is the code snippet which I used

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string DEVISE_PEPPER = "Here comes the devise pepper value";

        // One pass
        string pass = "reE8TuLcZ44XwRz";
        const string passHash = "$2a$10$1Rm.BC0hnF1laC7MFJ/B0eFu2rtG1Asy6fRqJVdqcfBO6LASn4Nqa";

        // Second pass
        const string secondPass = "FpRfaaqzNNRAum9";
        const string secondPassHash = "$2a$10$/Ex4x9LkvxIncaXhByqVP.YRdwRlZFJ7p4H96BfqHk1oGmw3YwLMC";

        // How Ruby BCyrpt verify? Ref - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-does-devise-keep-your-passwords-safe-d367f6e816eb/
        // 1. Fetch the input password
        // 2. Fetch the salt of the stored password
        // 3. Generate the hash from the password and salt using the same bcrypt version and cost factor 
        // 4. Check if the stored hash is the same one as the computed on step 3

        // Ref - https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/5d5636f03ac19e8188d99c044d4b5e90124313af/lib/devise/encryptor.rb#L14
        var finalPass = $"{secondPass}{DEVISE_PEPPER}";

        var verified = BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(finalPass, secondPassHash);
        var verifiedTxt = verified ? "verified!" : "didn't verified.";
        
        Console.WriteLine($"Password and hash {verifiedTxt}");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I was successfully able to [verify](https://prnt.sc/11p1za5) the password.